# Ansible: user entry getting added in crontab or cron file

Tags: ansible, cron

I have below Ansible `cron` task to enable/disable cron.

```yaml
- name: Enable/Disable cron
  cron:
    cron_file: /var/spool/cron/myuser
    user: myuser
    state: present
    disabled: true
    name: my cron
    job: cron script
    minute: "0"
    hour: "4"
```

But when I execute this crontab is created as

```bash
0 4 * * * myuser myscript.sh >> /tmp/myuser.log 2>&1
```

How can I avoid `myuser` getting added in cron entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation [`cron` module – Manage `cron.d` and `crontab` entries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html), the given [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html#examples) and your current description as it is

> *How can I avoid myuser getting added*

it is the expected behavior

```yaml
TASK [Enable or disable cron] *****************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: To use cron_file=... parameter you must specify user=... as well
```

and since it seems you are creating a cron file under `/var/spool/cron/myuser`.

Please take note that a dedicated cron file is something different than an entry in a cron table file (crontab).

A minimal example like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Enable or disable cron
    cron:
      cron_file: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test/cronfile"
      user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      state: present
      disabled: true
      name: my cron
      job: cron script
      minute: "0"
      hour: "4"
```

will result into a cron file of

```bash
cat cronfile
#Ansible: my cron
#0 4 * * * user cron script
```

or if `disabled: false` of

```bash
0 4 * * * user cron script
```

To summarize, you can't avoid it and would need an other approach.

**Further Readings**

about

- [Difference between `cron`, `crontab`, and `cronjob`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615673/)
- [`cronjob` entry in `crontab -e` vs `/etc/crontab`. Which one is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203120/)
- [Are `crontab -e` & `/etc/crontab` the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079013/)
- [Difference between `cron` and `crontab`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789148/)

---

<sub>*... you could to make sure the presence or absence of the cron file in example, but unfortunately there is almost no description of what you try to achieve.*</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately your comment doesn't add more information or details to your initial question, at least not for me. Maybe you can provide more, as well a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and by editing your question.